# Any invariant translation operator T can be represented by a multiplication operator on the Fourier transforms.

Tags: operator-theory, fourier-transform

In Harmonic Analysis by Stein E.
[image]

Why $T(e^{2\pi i\cdot \xi})=a(\xi)e^{2\pi ix\cdot \xi}$? I don't see how to deduce that.

Comment: How is $T$ defined in the text?

Comment: The text not says something about T